# How can I cause an element to move on mouse scroll using transform matrix?

Tags: jquery, css

I found this site here:

http://theme.pixflow.net/massive-dynamic/design-studio/#team-section

And what I am trying to do is have an element move on scroll just like the images are in the site I came across.

I noticed they are using transform instead of fixed. How would I accomplish this using CSS and/or jQuery?

Comment: You can use following link: https://markdalgleish.com/projects/stellar.js/demos/

Comment: Can I get an example of this please and thank you.

Comment: Can we have some feedback @user979331? If The answer below is not what you are looking for we can search for alternatives and different approaches.

Answer (score 10):

### The parallax effect:

What you are looking for is called a parallax effect:

> The **parallax** effect is an interactive effect in web design. Different design objects are positioned on different levels. Subsequently, the objects are moved at different speeds to each other, whereby space or movement is simulated.

[Source](https://kulturbanause.de/faq/parallax-effekt/) (translated from German to English).

---

```css
/* Tiny reset thingy */

body,
html {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

.wrapper {
  /* The height needs to be set to a fixed value for the effect to work.
   * 100vh is the full height of the viewport. */
  height: 100vh;
  /* The scaling of the images would add a horizontal scrollbar, so disable x overflow. */
  overflow-x: hidden;
  /* Enable scrolling on the page. */
  overflow-y: auto;
  /* Set the perspective to 2px. This is essentailly the simulated distance from the viewport to transformed objects.*/
  perspective: 2px;
}

.section {
  /* Needed for children to be absolutely positioned relative to the parent. */
  position: relative;
  /* The height of the container. Must be set, but it doesn't really matter what the value is. */
  height: 100vh;
  /* For text formatting. */
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
  color: white;
  text-shadow: 0 0 5px #000;
}

.parallax::after {
  /* Display and position the pseudo-element */
  content: " ";
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  right: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  left: 0;
  /* Move the pseudo-element back away from the camera,
   * then scale it back up to fill the viewport.
   * Because the pseudo-element is further away, it appears to move more slowly, like in real life. */
  transform: translateZ(-1px) scale(1.5);
  /* Force the background image to fill the whole element. */
  background-size: 100%;
  /* Keep the image from overlapping sibling elements. */
  z-index: -1;
}


/* The styling for the static div. */

.static {
  background: red;
}


/* Sets the actual background images to adorable kitties. This part is crucial. */

.bg1::after {
  background-image: url('https://placekitten.com/g/900/700');
}

.bg2::after {
  background-image: url('https://placekitten.com/g/800/600');
}
```

```html
<main class="wrapper">
  <section class="section parallax bg1">
    <h1>Such Adorableness</hi>
  </section>
  <section class="section static">
    <h1>Boring</h1>
  </section>
  <section class="section parallax bg2">
    <h1>SO FWUFFY AWWW</hi>
  </section>
</main>
```

[Source](https://codepen.io/tribex/pen/mWNWdz).

Although there are pure CSS parallax effects (like the example above) I prefer using jQuery as you have much easier configuration settings.

---

There are a lot of good libraries out there such as:

- [Stellar.js](https://markdalgleish.com/projects/stellar.js/demos/)
- [Parallax.js](https://github.com/pixelcog/parallax.js/)
- [Paroller.js](https://tgomilar.github.io/paroller.js/) (my personal favourite)
- [Rellax](https://github.com/dixonandmoe/rellax)
- ...

I made a (really basic) example of a parallax effect where I used [Rellax](https://github.com/dixonandmoe/rellax):

```js
(function(n,h){"function"===typeof define&&define.amd?define([],h):"object"===typeof module&&module.exports?module.exports=h():n.Rellax=h()})("undefined"!==typeof window?window:global,function(){var n=function(h,p){var a=Object.create(n.prototype),l=0,r=0,k=0,t=0,c=[],u=!0,B=window.requestAnimationFrame||window.webkitRequestAnimationFrame||window.mozRequestAnimationFrame||window.msRequestAnimationFrame||window.oRequestAnimationFrame||function(a){return setTimeout(a,1E3/60)},q=null,C=window.cancelAnimationFrame||
window.mozCancelAnimationFrame||clearTimeout,D=window.transformProp||function(){var a=document.createElement("div");if(null===a.style.transform){var b=["Webkit","Moz","ms"],e;for(e in b)if(void 0!==a.style[b[e]+"Transform"])return b[e]+"Transform"}return"transform"}();a.options={speed:-2,center:!1,wrapper:null,relativeToWrapper:!1,round:!0,vertical:!0,horizontal:!1,callback:function(){}};p&&Object.keys(p).forEach(function(d){a.options[d]=p[d]});h||(h=".rellax");var m="string"===typeof h?document.querySelectorAll(h):
[h];if(0<m.length){a.elems=m;if(a.options.wrapper&&!a.options.wrapper.nodeType)if(m=document.querySelector(a.options.wrapper))a.options.wrapper=m;else{console.warn("Rellax: The wrapper you're trying to use doesn't exist.");return}var w=function(){for(var d=0;d<c.length;d++)a.elems[d].style.cssText=c[d].style;c=[];r=window.innerHeight;t=window.innerWidth;x();for(d=0;d<a.elems.length;d++){var b=a.elems[d],e=b.getAttribute("data-rellax-percentage"),g=b.getAttribute("data-rellax-speed"),h=b.getAttribute("data-rellax-zindex")||
0,l=b.getAttribute("data-rellax-min"),n=b.getAttribute("data-rellax-max"),v=a.options.wrapper?a.options.wrapper.scrollTop:window.pageYOffset||document.documentElement.scrollTop||document.body.scrollTop;a.options.relativeToWrapper&&(v=(window.pageYOffset||document.documentElement.scrollTop||document.body.scrollTop)-a.options.wrapper.offsetTop);var f=a.options.vertical?e||a.options.center?v:0:0,k=a.options.horizontal?e||a.options.center?a.options.wrapper?a.options.wrapper.scrollLeft:window.pageXOffset||
document.documentElement.scrollLeft||document.body.scrollLeft:0:0;v=f+b.getBoundingClientRect().top;var m=b.clientHeight||b.offsetHeight||b.scrollHeight,p=k+b.getBoundingClientRect().left,q=b.clientWidth||b.offsetWidth||b.scrollWidth;f=e?e:(f-v+r)/(m+r);e=e?e:(k-p+t)/(q+t);a.options.center&&(f=e=.5);g=g?g:a.options.speed;e=y(e,f,g);b=b.style.cssText;f="";0<=b.indexOf("transform")&&(f=b.indexOf("transform"),f=b.slice(f),f=(k=f.indexOf(";"))?" "+f.slice(11,k).replace(/\s/g,""):" "+f.slice(11).replace(/\s/g,
""));c.push({baseX:e.x,baseY:e.y,top:v,left:p,height:m,width:q,speed:g,style:b,transform:f,zindex:h,min:l,max:n})}u&&(window.addEventListener("resize",w),u=!1);z()},x=function(){var d=l,b=k;l=a.options.wrapper?a.options.wrapper.scrollTop:(document.documentElement||document.body.parentNode||document.body).scrollTop||window.pageYOffset;k=a.options.wrapper?a.options.wrapper.scrollLeft:(document.documentElement||document.body.parentNode||document.body).scrollLeft||window.pageXOffset;a.options.relativeToWrapper&&
(l=((document.documentElement||document.body.parentNode||document.body).scrollTop||window.pageYOffset)-a.options.wrapper.offsetTop);return d!=l&&a.options.vertical||b!=k&&a.options.horizontal?!0:!1},y=function(d,b,e){var c={};d=100*e*(1-d);b=100*e*(1-b);c.x=a.options.round?Math.round(d):Math.round(100*d)/100;c.y=a.options.round?Math.round(b):Math.round(100*b)/100;return c},A=function(){x()&&!1===u&&z();q=B(A)},z=function(){for(var d,b=0;b<a.elems.length;b++){d=y((k-c[b].left+t)/(c[b].width+t),(l-
c[b].top+r)/(c[b].height+r),c[b].speed);var e=d.y-c[b].baseY,g=d.x-c[b].baseX;null!==c[b].min&&(a.options.vertical&&!a.options.horizontal&&(e=e<=c[b].min?c[b].min:e),a.options.horizontal&&!a.options.vertical&&(g=g<=c[b].min?c[b].min:g));null!==c[b].max&&(a.options.vertical&&!a.options.horizontal&&(e=e>=c[b].max?c[b].max:e),a.options.horizontal&&!a.options.vertical&&(g=g>=c[b].max?c[b].max:g));a.elems[b].style[D]="translate3d("+(a.options.horizontal?g:"0")+"px,"+(a.options.vertical?e:"0")+"px,"+c[b].zindex+
"px) "+c[b].transform}a.options.callback(d)};a.destroy=function(){for(var d=0;d<a.elems.length;d++)a.elems[d].style.cssText=c[d].style;u||(window.removeEventListener("resize",w),u=!0);C(q);q=null};w();A();a.refresh=w;return a}console.warn("Rellax: The elements you're trying to select don't exist.")};return n});

/*
 * This is the important part
 * This is the important part
 * This is the important part
 * This is the important part
 */
var rellax = new Rellax('.rellax', {
  center: false,
  wrapper: null,
  round: true,
  vertical: true,
  horizontal: false
});
```

```css
* {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

.flex {
  display: flex;
  flex-flow: row;
  justify-content: space-between;
  margin-top: 100px;
}

body {
  height: 2000px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="flex">
  <div>
    <h1>
      DESI<br>GNER
    </h1>
    <p>
      No need to worry about your ranking on Google and other search engines. Massive Dynamic is a SEO optimized WordPress theme and control how your websites are displayed in search results.Massive Dynamic is a fully responsive theme. Smartphone.
    </p>
  </div>

  <div class="rellax" data-rellax-speed="5">
    <img src="http://via.placeholder.com/250x460" alt="">
  </div>
</div>
```

Note: For some strange reason I couldn't include the library via `scripts` tags so I pasted the minified version of the script inside the script field. At the bottom you find the important part which initializes the parallax.

I also made a (more complex) example where I used [Paroller.js](https://tgomilar.github.io/paroller.js/). I think this example is the closest to the scrolling behaviour and methods you provided in the link:

```js
/**
 * jQuery plugin paroller.js v1.4.6
 * https://github.com/tgomilar/paroller.js
 * preview: https://tgomilar.github.io/paroller/
 **/
(function(factory) {
  'use strict';
  if (typeof define === 'function' && define.amd) {
    define('parollerjs', ['jquery'], factory);
  } else if (typeof module === 'object' && typeof module.exports === 'object') {
    module.exports = factory(require('jquery'));
  } else {
    factory(jQuery);
  }
})(function($) {
  'use strict';

  var working = false;
  var scrollAction = function() {
    working = false;
  };

  var setDirection = {
    bgVertical: function(elem, bgOffset) {
      return elem.css({
        'background-position': 'center ' + -bgOffset + 'px'
      });
    },
    bgHorizontal: function(elem, bgOffset) {
      return elem.css({
        'background-position': -bgOffset + 'px' + ' center'
      });
    },
    vertical: function(elem, elemOffset, transition, oldTransform) {
      (oldTransform === 'none' ? oldTransform = '' : true);
      return elem.css({
        '-webkit-transform': 'translateY(' + elemOffset + 'px)' + oldTransform,
        '-moz-transform': 'translateY(' + elemOffset + 'px)' + oldTransform,
        'transform': 'translate(0,' + elemOffset + 'px)' + oldTransform,
        'transition': transition,
        'will-change': 'transform'
      });
    },
    horizontal: function(elem, elemOffset, transition, oldTransform) {
      (oldTransform === 'none' ? oldTransform = '' : true);
      return elem.css({
        '-webkit-transform': 'translateX(' + elemOffset + 'px)' + oldTransform,
        '-moz-transform': 'translateX(' + elemOffset + 'px)' + oldTransform,
        'transform': 'translate(' + elemOffset + 'px, 0)' + oldTransform,
        'transition': transition,
        'will-change': 'transform'
      });
    }
  };

  var setMovement = {
    factor: function(elem, width, options) {
      var dataFactor = elem.data('paroller-factor');
      var factor = (dataFactor) ? dataFactor : options.factor;
      if (width < 576) {
        var dataFactorXs = elem.data('paroller-factor-xs');
        var factorXs = (dataFactorXs) ? dataFactorXs : options.factorXs;
        return (factorXs) ? factorXs : factor;
      } else if (width <= 768) {
        var dataFactorSm = elem.data('paroller-factor-sm');
        var factorSm = (dataFactorSm) ? dataFactorSm : options.factorSm;
        return (factorSm) ? factorSm : factor;
      } else if (width <= 1024) {
        var dataFactorMd = elem.data('paroller-factor-md');
        var factorMd = (dataFactorMd) ? dataFactorMd : options.factorMd;
        return (factorMd) ? factorMd : factor;
      } else if (width <= 1200) {
        var dataFactorLg = elem.data('paroller-factor-lg');
        var factorLg = (dataFactorLg) ? dataFactorLg : options.factorLg;
        return (factorLg) ? factorLg : factor;
      } else if (width <= 1920) {
        var dataFactorXl = elem.data('paroller-factor-xl');
        var factorXl = (dataFactorXl) ? dataFactorXl : options.factorXl;
        return (factorXl) ? factorXl : factor;
      } else {
        return factor;
      }
    },
    bgOffset: function(offset, factor) {
      return Math.round(offset * factor);
    },
    transform: function(offset, factor, windowHeight, height) {
      return Math.round((offset - (windowHeight / 2) + height) * factor);
    }
  };

  var clearPositions = {
    background: function(elem) {
      return elem.css({
        'background-position': 'unset'
      });
    },
    foreground: function(elem) {
      return elem.css({
        'transform': 'unset',
        'transition': 'unset'
      });
    }
  };

  $.fn.paroller = function(options) {
    var windowHeight = $(window).height();
    var documentHeight = $(document).height();

    // default options
    var options = $.extend({
      factor: 0, // - to +
      factorXs: 0, // - to +
      factorSm: 0, // - to +
      factorMd: 0, // - to +
      factorLg: 0, // - to +
      factorXl: 0, // - to +
      transition: 'transform .1s ease', // CSS transition
      type: 'background', // foreground
      direction: 'vertical' // horizontal
    }, options);

    return this.each(function() {
      var $this = $(this);
      var width = $(window).width();
      var offset = $this.offset().top;
      var scrollOffset = 0;
      var height = $this.outerHeight();

      var dataType = $this.data('paroller-type');
      var dataDirection = $this.data('paroller-direction');
      var dataTransition = $this.data('paroller-transition');
      var oldTransform = $this.css('transform');

      var transition = (dataTransition) ? dataTransition : options.transition;
      var type = (dataType) ? dataType : options.type;
      var direction = (dataDirection) ? dataDirection : options.direction;
      var factor = 0;
      var bgOffset = setMovement.bgOffset(offset, factor);
      var transform = setMovement.transform(offset, factor, windowHeight, height);

      if (type === 'background') {
        if (direction === 'vertical') {
          setDirection.bgVertical($this, bgOffset);
        } else if (direction === 'horizontal') {
          setDirection.bgHorizontal($this, bgOffset);
        }
      } else if (type === 'foreground') {
        if (direction === 'vertical') {
          setDirection.vertical($this, transform, transition, oldTransform);
        } else if (direction === 'horizontal') {
          setDirection.horizontal($this, transform, transition, oldTransform);
        }
      }

      $(window).on('resize', function() {
        var scrolling = $(this).scrollTop();
        width = $(window).width();
        offset = $this.offset().top;
        height = $this.outerHeight();
        factor = setMovement.factor($this, width, options);

        bgOffset = Math.round(offset * factor);
        let transformPre = Math.round((offset - (windowHeight / 2) + height) * factor);
        if (!scrollTop) {
          scrollOffset = transformPre
        }
        transform = transformPre - scrollOffset

        if (!working) {
          window.requestAnimationFrame(scrollAction);
          working = true;
        }

        if (type === 'background') {
          clearPositions.background($this);
          if (direction === 'vertical') {
            setDirection.bgVertical($this, bgOffset);
          } else if (direction === 'horizontal') {
            setDirection.bgHorizontal($this, bgOffset);
          }
        } else if ((type === 'foreground') && (scrolling <= documentHeight)) {
          clearPositions.foreground($this);
          if (direction === 'vertical') {
            setDirection.vertical($this, transform, transition);
          } else if (direction === 'horizontal') {
            setDirection.horizontal($this, transform, transition);
          }
        }
      });

      $(window).on('scroll', function() {
        var scrolling = $(this).scrollTop();
        var scrollTop = $(document).scrollTop();
        factor = setMovement.factor($this, width, options);
        let transformPre = Math.round(((offset - (windowHeight / 2) + height) - scrolling) * factor);
        if (!scrollTop) {
          scrollOffset = transformPre
        }
        transform = transformPre - scrollOffset

        if (!working) {
          window.requestAnimationFrame(scrollAction);
          working = true;
        }

        if (type === 'background') {
          if (direction === 'vertical') {
            setDirection.bgVertical($this, bgOffset);
          } else if (direction === 'horizontal') {
            setDirection.bgHorizontal($this, bgOffset);
          }
        } else if ((type === 'foreground') && (scrolling <= documentHeight)) {
          if (direction === 'vertical') {
            setDirection.vertical($this, transform, transition, oldTransform);
          } else if (direction === 'horizontal') {
            setDirection.horizontal($this, transform, transition, oldTransform);
          }
        }
      });
    });
  };
});
$(".my-element").paroller({
  factor: 0.6, // multiplier for scrolling speed and offset
  factorXs: 1, // multiplier for scrolling speed and offset
  type: 'foreground', // background, foreground
  direction: 'vertical', // vertical, horizontal
  transition: 'transform 0.2s ease-in' // CSS transition
});

$(document).scroll();
```

```css
* {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

.flex {
  display: flex;
  flex-flow: row;
  justify-content: space-between;
  margin-top: 100px;
}

body {
  height: 2000px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="flex">
  <div>
    <h1>
      DESI<br>GNER
    </h1>
    <p>
      No need to worry about your ranking on Google and other search engines. Massive Dynamic is a SEO optimized WordPress theme and control how your websites are displayed in search results.Massive Dynamic is a fully responsive theme. Smartphone.
    </p>
  </div>

  <div class="mega my-element">
    <img src="http://via.placeholder.com/250x460" alt="">
  </div>
</div>
```

**Attention**: At the moment Parroler.js has a bug which makes the image jump on initial scroll. It has been [discussed on GitHub](https://github.com/tgomilar/paroller.js/issues/61) and there is a [pull request](https://github.com/tgomilar/paroller.js/pull/62)  **which I implemented in this example so the bug does not exist anymore!**

---

In case you want to make your own parallax script the logic behind it is relatively simple. Take a look at this example:

```js
// Y axis scroll speed
var velocity = 0.5;

function update() {
  var pos = $(window).scrollTop();
  $('.container').each(function() {
    var $element = $(this);
    // subtract some from the height b/c of the padding
    var height = $element.height() - 18;
    $(this).css('backgroundPosition', '50% ' + Math.round((height - pos) * velocity) + 'px');
  });
};

$(window).bind('scroll', update);
```

```css
.container {
  padding: 200px 20px 200px 20px;
  text-align: center;
  color: #FFF;
  font-weight: bold;
}

.section-1 {
  background-image: url(http://static4.wikia.nocookie.net/__cb20130612023354/harrypotter/images/d/d1/Gradient-blue-background.jpg);
  background-position: center;
}

.section-2 {
  background-image: url(http://th00.deviantart.net/fs49/PRE/f/2009/207/e/d/Orange_Desktop_Background_by_The_Dogfather.png);
  background-position: center;
}

.section-3 {
  background-image: url(http://oaklandbaptist.org/media/Green-Background.jpg);
  background-position: center;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="container section-1">
  Welcome to this test!
</div>
<div class="container section-2">
  There is more cool stuff below...
</div>
<div class="container section-3">
  We are done with cool things!
</div>
```

[Source](https://jsfiddle.net/Aaron3219/Lxqp2m8b/).

The only thing to do is to calculate the offset and apply it to the object. In this exmaple she/he used the `background-position`. However, you can of course just change it to the according `transform` values or even use `position: relative` and the `top; bottom; left; right;` attributes.

You also may have noticed that the parallax on your provided link has some kind of delay on their parallax effect. This is because they use a `transition` which uses `ease`. So if you want that effect you can just add it to your CSS. Paroller.js even offers the option to add a `transition` effect by default (which I added in my example).

---

If you have any questions let me know, I hope I directed you on the right track so you can go on from here.